# Castle Windsor Map Named Component To Specific Property

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Following scenario:

We use the Fluent API to register all components in an assembly and two components tyepof(A) with named keys. Another class B with two properties typeof(A) should get the named components injected.

Sample:

```
public class A : IA {}

public class B : IB
{
    [Named("first")]
    public IA First { get; set; }

    [Named("second")]
    public IA Second { get; set; }
}

// ...

container.Register(Component.For<IA>().Instance(new A(value1)).Named("first"));
container.Register(Component.For<IA>().Instance(new A(value2)).Named("second"));

// ...
var b = container.Resolve<IB>(); // named instances of A get injected to B using the Named attribute
```

Is this possible with an attribute like Named or only with the Xml Config?

Comment: BTW `B` should get `IA` injected, not the concrete `A`

Comment: True, this is actually what I wanted to type. ;) Fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to do this in Windsor is using [service overrides](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx#In-line_service_dependencies_1). In your example, when you register `B` you'd do it like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IB>().ImplementedBy<B>()
                     .ServiceOverrides(new {First = "first", Second = "second"}));
```

(there are other ways to express this, check the linked docs)

Using a `Named` attribute as you propose pollutes the code with unrelated concerns (`B` should not care about what `A`s get injected)

Comment: I see. Yes, it makes sense and I like the non-invasive approach, although you have the risk that the property of the anonymous type is mistyped. I guess this would raise an exception, so an unit test for the registration would cover this?

Comment: @Rene Schulte: and with the `Named` attribute approach you run the risk of mistyping the name of some component. It's a downside of most (all?) IoC containers: you lose some static type checks.

Comment: @Rene Schulte: also, you could use Expressions instead of strings to represent properties, see http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Strongly+Typed+property+wiring+with+Fluent+Registration+API

Comment: Note that ServiceOverrides is now obsolete.  Use DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent()) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would solve this problem using `DependsOn` and incorporating the `nameof` expression (introduced in C# 6.0):

```cs
container.Register
(
    Component.For<IA>()
        .Instance(new A(value1))
        .Named("first"),
    Component.For<IA>()
         .Instance(new  A(value2))
         .Named("second"),
    Component.For<IB>()
          .ImplementedBy<B>()
          .DependsOn
          (
              Dependency.OnComponent(nameof(B.First), "first"),
              Dependency.OnComponent(nameof(B.Second), "second")
          )      
)
```

`Dependency.OnComponent` has many overrides, but in this case the first parameter is the property name, and the second parameter is the component name.

See [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md#explicit-service-dependencies-dependencyoncomponent) for more documentation.