# How to inject different dependencies that depends on argument name using Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a structure like:

```
public class Processor<T>
{
    public Processor(IManager<T> xmlManager, IManager<T> memoryManager)
    {

    }
}

public interface IManager<T>
{

}

public class Manager<T> : IManager<T>
{
    private readonly IProvider _provider;

    public Manager(IProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }
}

public interface IProvider  {   }

public class XmlProvider : IProvider {  }

public class MemoryProvider : IProvider {   }
```

I need to inject to Processor class two instances of Manager class but with different injections. So hardcoded I need:

```
var p = new Processor<T>(new Manager<T>(new XmlProvider()) , new Manager<T>(new MemoryProvider()))
```

Also i need resolve this using open generic type T.

I cannot figure out how to configure container to manage this. I know there is `.DependsOn(Property.ForKey("xmlManager").Eq()` directive. But I cannot understand what to write in `Eq()` except a hardcoded implementation. Providers have their own dependencies. So it is not clever to write `.Eq(new Manager<T>(new XmlProvide(new OtherInjection(new AnotherOne()))))`. And there I cannot use  an open generic.

**UPD 1**
Mr NightOwl888. About logic. One provider is for storing data in memory Cache. Second provider is for storing data storing data in xml files. Some kind of 2 level cache model. It will not break if i swap two parameters (like Steven said) but it will work not as it was designed (cause of diffenert speed of retrieving of information).

Comment: You could use property injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030431/castle-windsor-map-named-component-to-specific-property or see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325699/castle-windsor-how-to-map-named-instance-in-constructor-injection

Comment: What would happen if you accidentally swap the two parameters around? Would your `Processor` break? If so, you are violating the Liskov Substitution Principle, and you might want to rethink your design.

Comment: I agree with @Steven. The whole point of making an abstraction (interface) is so you can swap the implementation without the `Processor` knowing what concrete type of `IManager<T>` you are dealing with. With your design, the `Processor` knows these details, and if a 3rd `IManager<T>`  type is introduced later, it is a breaking change to `Processor`. Does `Processor` require *more than one* `IManager<T>` to execute, or does it *select one* based on a condition? `Processor` is violating the Single Responsibility Principle by including this logic. It is also unclear which logic from the design.

Comment: I think @Steven and @NightOwl888 are right. I updated info about logic. Also after disccusion with @DragonFire I've undestood that architecture is bad. Managers should implement 1 interface cause they have same methods and purpose. But they are also different in my context. So I need to  distinguish them by another interface. For example `IXmlCachManager` and `IInMemoryCacheManager`. And than resolve them by this interfaces

Comment: @Rit, thank for links. Using new interfaces (previous my comment) and  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5761999/980003) link everything is resolved. Vuhahaha. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't work with Windsor, but common solution looks like

```
public class ManagerFactory // register it in container
{
   public IManager<T> Create<T>(IProvider provider) { return ... }
}

public class Processor<T>
{
    public Processor(ManagerFactory factory, IEnumerable<IProvider> providers)
    {
       myManagers = providers.Select(provider => factory.Create<T>(provider).ToList();
    }
}
```

Usually, you can register many implementations of some interface (in your case for IProvider), so container can inject them all